# Python method return value

Tags: python

I am having a bit of trouble with a python class I have created.  I have tried to create the most simple class possible to debug it by stripping out any unrelated code.  I still have the same issue.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.row = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

    def get_row(self):
        return self.row

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MyClass()

    b = a.row

    b.remove('1')

    print(a.row)
    print(b)
```

The output is:

```
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

What is happening is when I do the b.remove('1') it removes the first entry from the b list as expected but when I look at a.row it has also been removed from it.  My understanding of classes and return values it that b should have been a copy of a, it appears to behave more like a pointer in this case.

Any help in explaining how this has actually worked would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid your understanding is incorrect. All values are objects in python, and attributes and names are *references* to these objects. `a.row` is the reference to the list, you are merely making a copy of that **reference**, not the value itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Python documentation:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.

([source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html))

Basically, you'll need to explicitly make a new copy of a.row. You're right that it's behaving like a pointer.

List-specific example, with pictures:

> Python doesn’t have variables like C. In C a variable is not just a name, it is a set of bits; a variable exists somewhere in memory. In Python variables are just tags attached to objects.
>
> Consider the following statement:
>
> a = [1, 2, 3]
>
> It means that a points to the list [1, 2, 3] we just created, but a is not the list. If we do:
>
> b = a
>
> We didn't copy the list referenced by a. We just created a new tag b and attached it to the list pointed by a. Like in the picture below:
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [precheur.org](http://henry.precheur.org/python/list1.png))</sub>
>
> [ ... ]
>
> Now we want to copy the list referenced by a. We need to create a new list to attach b to it.
>
> [image]

([source](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list))

Since a.row is a list, try this:

```
b = list(a.row)
```

Comment: It's all about the difference between mutable/immutable data types in Python. Nice graphic.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Milo Price, when you do `b = a.row`, b now stores a reference to a.row. So when you change b, it will also change a.row. You can also try slicing the list, ie, `b = a.row[:]`